# How to make textfield mandatory based on value of pathfield in aem

Tags: jquery, adobe, aem

My question is in aem dialog if we have two fields one is pathfield and another one is textfiled, Now I want to make textfield mandatory if some value is entered in pathfield and also if no value is entered in pathfield then I dont want to make textfield mandatory.

Please help if someone knows the answer

Comment: You can only do this with your own clientlib. The simplest would be a custom form validation. (I found no good example, but start here https://www.adobe.io/experience-manager/reference-materials/6-5/granite-ui/api/jcr_root/libs/granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/textfield/index.html and then use google). Or for the full solution you could check the show-hide lib from ACS commons https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/acs-aem-commons/blob/master/ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/acs-commons/touchui-widgets/showhidedialogfields/source/requiredvalidation.js

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Granite UI components, this, for the most part, is already resolved by setting

`required="{Boolean}true"`

which is often fine is all you want to check is that the user put something in the field.

But, for instance, if you have a multi-field, or RTE (resourceType of cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog/richtext), or an icon picker from ACS commons, or even your custom-developed dialog field, you may need to write a validator for a mandatory field and/or any other custom validation requirements.

There's a great article about writing custom validators here https://blogs.perficient.com/2017/11/06/aem-touch-ui-dialog-validation-new-best-practice-use-foundation-validation/